# How do I loop images in a div downwards infinitely using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am working on an assignment with the description of:

Create a JavaScript loop using images to get the output as picture below. You can use any images and it is requiring to use maximum 5 images. The images should be loop infinitely. Use your own creativity to design the layout.

[image: 2]

But I have no idea how to work on that, I only created a div with three images in it and stuck on the javascript part.

This is my code:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 27vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 1px;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <img class="car" src="images/car1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img class="car" src="images/car2.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img class="car" src="images/car3.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what I've got now:

[image: 1]

Comment: Are you trying to make that a background (that goes on right down the page)? If not, could you describe what 'infinitely' means here?

Comment: It means the images should repeat many times like the example I gave, no it is not a background. sorry if my english is bad

Comment: But maybe using the images as a background is an option? Have you looked into CSS [background-img](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)? And then especially the "repeat" options.

Comment: It requires using javascript loop to achieve the output

Comment: Can you edit the post and show us the code for how to do, what you call, "text loop"? That might help us understand exactly why you need to repeat the same images for three rows.

Comment: You can't have an infinite number of elements so could you explain in what sense this isn't a background? How many elements do you actually want (as opposed to how many instances of those images).

Comment: can i make it repeat like 10 times if it is a background using javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Here is something to get you started. I changed `<div class="container">` to `<div id="container">` and added another container within that one: `.box-container`.

The basic idea is to clone a container with the initial images, and then append (add) them to your original container.

```js
let numberOfRows = 3;
const containerDiv = document.getElementById('container');

// get first element in #container, which is just one child: .box-container
let boxContainerDiv = containerDiv.children[0];

while (numberOfRows) {
  numberOfRows--;

  // clone the node
  let clonedChild = boxContainerDiv.cloneNode(true);
  
  // add the clone node to #container
  containerDiv.appendChild(clonedChild); 
}
```

```css
.box-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 1px;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box-container">
    <div class="box">
      <img class="car" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.png?text=1">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img class="car" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.png?text=2">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img class="car" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.png?text=3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```